# Federated Log off keeping user logged on application

Tags: c#, .net, adfs2.0, acs

I have an application that has integration with ACS / ADFS. I'm having a quite strange behaviour.

I'm logging off the user, Abandoning the session, and redirecting to ACS with Cleanup param.

The user is effectively logged off from ADFS and from ACS but on return to the application, redirect to the Reply parameter, the user is still logged in the application.

The WIF code does not execute again, and no token is present, only IClaimsPrincipal is still present and the Session is present too.

Anyone has heard of this behaviour or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although this should be executed internally by the framework, I found that clearing the ACS Cookies manually resolved the issue.

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
string famResult = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(fam.Issuer, fam.Reply, null);
fam.FederationConfiguration.CookieHandler.Delete();
```

Issue resolved.

Thanks to everyone.